# JTextField is disabled when added in JPopupMenu

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to include a `JTextField` in a `JPopupMenu` (the menu is part of JTable, showed on right click). The thing is that the `JTextField` although visible appears disabled/non-editable. I've created a small sample the reproduces the problem.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
throws Exception 
{
    final JPopupMenu popupTable = new JPopupMenu();

    JLabel findLabel = new JLabel("Filter for:");
    findLabel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(60, 20));

    final JTextField findTextField = new JTextField();
    findTextField.setColumns(10);

    final JPanel container = new JPanel();
    container.setBackground(new JMenuItem().getBackground()); // panel must have the same background with JMenuItems
    container.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT, 10, 0));
    container.add(findLabel);
    container.add(findTextField);

    popupTable.add(container);

    JButton button = new JButton("Action");
    JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
    buttonPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
    buttonPanel.add(button);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    panel.add(popupTable, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    panel.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(900, 800);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    frame.getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    button.addActionListener
    (
        new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                popupTable.setVisible(true);
                Point pos = new Point();
                pos.x = (frame.getWidth() / 2);
                pos.y = (frame.getHeight() / 2);
                popupTable.setLocation(pos);
            }
        }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comment the `popupTable.setVisible(true);`

And add in the end

```
popupTable.show(frame, pos.x, pos.y);
```

To provide container window for the popup

Comment: Thank you for your help. Have fun